# Change MagnifierGlass Height and Width

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

When I create `FireMonkey` app , and drop `MagnifierGlass` component , I can see in the `Object Inspector` **Height** and **Width** properties of the `MagnifierGlass` , but I can't change those properties , So :

- Why we can't change `properties` **Height** and **Width** ?
- If i need to make it **bigger** or **smaller** , How can i do that?

  **Note:** I'm using  `Delphi 10 Seattle`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a bug in default style in Delphi 10 Seattle for MagnifierGlass but only if LoupeMode is set for Circle, so easiest way is to change LoupeMode for Rectangle, then you'll be able to resize it on form.
If you want to use it with LoupeMode=Circle, you can fix one of the custom styles, for example as following

In this file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Redist\styles\Fmx\Win10Modern.Style` find following lines

```
  object TLayout
    StyleName = 'magnifierglassstyle'
    FixedWidth = 150
    FixedHeight = 150
```

replace it with

```
  object TLayout
    StyleName = 'magnifierglassstyle'
    Size.Width = 50.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 50.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
```

Now drop StyleBook component on form and set FileName property to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Redist\styles\Fmx\Win10Modern.Style`

Set `StyleBook` property of your Form to `StyleBook1`

Now if you drop `MagnifierGlass` on form you'll be able to resize it.

This is not needed in Delphi 10.1 Berlin since you can edit FixedHeight and FixedWidth properties in the Style Editor there.

**Update**

I've created [bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16775) about this issue